# Factory Size of Hard Drive - C#

Tags: c#

There are so many piece of codes which return hard drive size in Mega Byte.
But I have a simple question.

You buy a 256 GB Hard drive but those methods return for example 234 GB.
I know there are differences between the Factory size and the exact size. But how Can I get the Factory Size? any class or method? Or I should just use a `switch case` or `if else` and doing it myself?

```
        ManagementClass mc = new ManagementClass("Win32_DiskDrive");
        double MemSize = 0;
        foreach (ManagementObject mo in mc.GetInstances())
        {
            if (mo["InterfaceType"].ToString() == "IDE")
            {
                MemSize += Convert.ToInt64(mo["Size"].ToString());
                break;
            }
        }
        return GetSize(MemSize);
```

This is a simple method getting Hard drive size using `wmi` and method `GetSize` will convert the size to GB. But it will not return Factory Size at all.

The GetSize Method:

```
    public string GetSize(double len)
    {
        string[] sizes = { "B", "KB", "MB", "GB", "TB" };
        int order = 0;
        while (len >= 1024 && order < sizes.Length - 1)
        {
            order++;
            len = len / 1024;
        }
        return String.Format("{0:0.##} {1}", Math.Floor(len), sizes[order]);
```

If I divide the size by 1000, It will get closer to Factory Size but not the exact size, for example for 256 GB will return 240 GB.

Comment: Factory sizes are often (always?) measured in multiples of 1000 instead of 1024 because it looks like a bigger size than it is. You're better off sticking with what you have here.

Comment: @DavidG is there any way fixing `GetSize` method returning Factory Size?

Comment: Just replace 1024 with 1000 in your GetSize method to get the "factory" size.

Comment: It will get near but not the exact Factory size.

Comment: Nobody cares about factory size though, I'm not sure why you really want to show that.

Comment: I'm writing a System Info tool.

Comment: But factory size isn't a useful metric for system info, actual size is. In fact, usable size is even more important.

Comment: yeah, but out there, there are so many system info tools which return the exact factory size.

Comment: Which begs the question... why are you writing another one? :)

Comment: You say "I know there are differences between the Factory size and the exact size." but then later say you want the "exact factory size".  So you want the _exact_ factory size even though you acknowledge that the factory size and the exact size are two different things?  Also, how would you expect WMI/Windows/etc. to know (or care) how to calculate the factory size of a disk when the "factory size" is known to be misleading marketing information?  There is no `GetInflatedDiskSize` method, unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

Hard drive are sold with the sizes calculated in base 10 so 1000 megabytes is 1 gigabyte. Technically we as techy types are using the wrong terminology anyway as 1024 bytes should really be called 1 [mebibyte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mebibyte).

So to calculate the different sizes you need to divide by 1000 instead of 1024. You can easily modify your size calculation to take that as a parameter, for example:

```
public enum SizeType
{
    Actual = 1024,
    Factory = 1000
}

public string GetSize(double len, SizeType sizeType)
{
    string[] sizes = { "B", "KB", "MB", "GB", "TB" };
    int order = 0;
    while (len >= (int)sizeType && order < sizes.Length - 1)
    {
        order++;
        len = len / (int)sizeType;
    }
    return String.Format("{0:0.##} {1}", Math.Floor(len), sizes[order]);
}
```

Now you can get the values like this:

```
var actual = GetSize(bytes, SizeType.Actual);
var factory = GetSize(bytes, SizeType.Factory);
```

Comment: The question's most recent edit adds that dividing by 1000 still does not give them whatever value they're looking for, but +1, anyways, for extending their method to account for varying degrees of truthiness regarding disk size.  They'll just need to add a third enum value once they figure out the magic number that gives them the arbitrary disk sizes they're looking for.  I agree with your comments above that the premise of trying to convert an accurate number to an inaccurate one is flawed.

Comment: There are also various things that "steal" the space you can actually use, that's probably where the difference is here.

Answer (score 1):

The factory sizes are always divided by 1000 instead of 1024.
See https://www.sevenforums.com/hardware-devices/23890-hdds-advertized-size-vs-actual-size.html for an explanation of how the calculation works.

Short version: divide your result in GB by 0.9313226 to get the actual size.